# LiPo Battery HAT behavior

Tags: battery, power-management, hat, ups

I was reading the description for [LiPo Battery HAT for Raspberry Pi](https://thepihut.com/products/lipo-battery-hat-for-raspberry-pi) and it at best seems very unclear to me:

> This is not a UPS! The Raspberry Pi will restart when you connect it to the Pi.

What does this restart mean? Will it reboot when I attach cable to charge the hat or will it reboot when I attach it to an already running Pi? Would it be always starting RPi in case I shut it down (`shutdown`) and keep the cable plugged in RPi?

Also, what would happen if I kept the battery constantly charging and the `OUT USB` plugged to RPi (in case it won't get powered directly through the pins)?

I'd expect nothing strange happening (at least to the battery) as it mentioned protection against overcharging, shortcircuit and others, however the `This is not a UPS!` makes me sceptical.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because although you have asked a reasonable question, you are asking your question in the wrong place! No one at RPi SE wrote that, and the best we can do is ***guess*** at the what the author meant. Ask the vendor!!  I can appreciate your confusion - it's a simple enough statement, but the absence of any context makes it unclear. The [wiki](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/Li-polymer_Battery_HAT) is no better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation appears to have been written by a non-English-speaking person. I won't waste my time trying to translate illiterate gibberish, but I'll try to provide a *quasi-answer* here that might be of some help to someone not familiar with the RPi:

The RPi lacks much of the power circuitry found on conventional laptop & desktop computers. This is due to the fact that RPi was designed primarily to be a **low cost learning tool**. You'll find no power on/off button on the RPi, and it has no sleep or suspend state.

Instead, to ***properly & safely*** remove power from an RPi, you must first issue a `halt`/`shutdown`/`poweroff` command. Following this command, the RPi ceases to be *operational*, and power may be removed without risk of file system corruption. However, the RPi will continue to consume power after the `halt`/`shutdown`/`poweroff` command. The only way for the RPi to reach a zero power consumption state is to disconnect the RPi from its 5V power source.

After the RPi receives a `halt`/`shutdown`/`poweroff` command, the only way to restore it to an operating state (reboot) is to *power cycle* the 5V input power. There are typically a couple of ways to do this, depending upon the model, but the method that works for all models is to remove the 5V input power, and then reconnect it.

With that in mind, let's now *revisit* the mystery statement:

> This is not a UPS! The Raspberry Pi will restart when you connect it to the Pi.

We know the following:

> RPi will restart/reboot from a halted state - or a powered off state - when power is applied.

Perhaps what your vendor/manufacturer is *trying* to say is that this HAT is not a UPS in the sense that it cannot power the RPi while the battery is being charged? But that's only a guess... it *cannot* be a definitive answer to your question because it requires an *assumption* - an *interpretation* - of what they wrote. However, it is *self-evident* that what they wrote is poorly-worded and confusing.